# Getting error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2048 at everything I'm doing in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

whatever I'm doing in Eclipse, I get an error.

At start up I get an error at Java tooling initializing. I get an error when I want to open a type. And it's always the same error.

For example, when opening a type I get:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Cache refresh".
2048
```

The error at the start up also prints the error code as 2048.

I'm using the most up to date version of Eclipse.

Do you know a way to fix this issue?

edit:
Here the stack trace of the error at Java tooling initializing:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2048
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.index.DiskIndex.readStreamChars(DiskIndex.java:870)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.index.DiskIndex.initialize(DiskIndex.java:370)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.index.Index.<init>(Index.java:96)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.indexing.IndexManager.getIndex(IndexManager.java:248)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.indexing.IndexManager.getIndexes(IndexManager.java:309)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.PatternSearchJob.getIndexes(PatternSearchJob.java:81)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.PatternSearchJob.ensureReadyToRun(PatternSearchJob.java:50)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.processing.JobManager.performConcurrentJob(JobManager.java:174)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.searchAllTypeNames(BasicSearchEngine.java:1122)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine.searchAllTypeNames(SearchEngine.java:713)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.dialogs.FilteredTypesSelectionDialog$ConsistencyRunnable.refreshSearchIndices(FilteredTypesSelectionDialog.java:653)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.dialogs.FilteredTypesSelectionDialog$ConsistencyRunnable.run(FilteredTypesSelectionDialog.java:636)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.dialogs.FilteredTypesSelectionDialog.reloadCache(FilteredTypesSelectionDialog.java:679)
 at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.FilteredItemsSelectionDialog$RefreshCacheJob.run(FilteredItemsSelectionDialog.java:1502)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?  What language settings?

Comment: Windows Vista. The language is German.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now did a scan disk and that seems to be the solution for the problem.